# What happens in reloading but not in navigation in angular?

Tags: zurb-foundation, angular8

I am working in angular-9 , there are many things which works on reloading, but not after navigation. eg: there are two components A and B. and another component c have a reveal modal code(in foundation). 
c component is to be included in both A and B.from component A through navigation I can move to component B which is a another page.

c.ts:

```
import { FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder,FormGroup, FormGroupDirective } from '@angular/forms';
loginFormControl:FormGroup;
ngOnInit() {
    $('#loginModal').foundation();
    this.loginFormControl = this.formBuilder.group({
        phone_number: ''
    });
}
```

c.html

```
<div class="reveal" id="loginModal" data-reveal>
    <form class="loginForm" [formGroup]="loginFormControl" 
    (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <input placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" formControlName="phone_number">
        <button type="submit" class="button">LOGIN</button>
    </form>
    <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

If I open the modal 'c' in both of the pages A and B on a click of two buttons on both pages with `$('#loginModal').foundation('open');` in A.ts and B.ts files, it results me with some unexpected behavior. 
 1. the modal is open in both the pages. no issue related to view
 2. But events of that modal(click,change) or if I enter phone number, It doesn't accept it from user. Even there no event works in a page until i refresh or reload the page. 
 3. After refreshing a page it will work on that page (including all
    events and inputs), there won't be any issue in that page after reloading. but as i navigate to another component B, then it's(c) events and input won't work until i refresh this page too. this same will happen again with component A.

I haven't reach at any solution of this till now and why is this happening. Please let me know if anyone have solution of my problem. It would be fruitful for me.